# Why can't Perl's open find my file?

Tags: perl, file-io

I am new to Perl coding.
I am facing a problem while executing a small script I have:
[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) is not able to find the file which I am giving as an argument.

The file is available:

```
 ls -l DLmissing_months.sql
-rwxr-xr-x   1 tlmwrk61 aimsys      2842 May 16 09:44 DLmissing_months.sql
```

My Perl script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $this_line = "";
my $do_next = 0;
my $file_name = $ARGV[0];
open( my $fh, '<', '$file_name')
    or die "Error opening file - $!\n";
close($fh);
```

executing the Perl script :

```
> new.pl DLmissing_months.sql
Error opening file - No such file or directory
```

What is the problem with my Perl script?

Comment: I would also highly suggest to you, that you use [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/autodie-2.10/lib/autodie.pm). It will save you from having to type the annoying `or die` statements. Of, which you forget to check `close($fh)` (and most people wouldn't think to do it anyway).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Single quotes don't interpolate. Instead of opening `DLmissing_months.sql`, you are trying to open a file called `$file_name`. Use double quotes to make things interpolate. In this case, you can just use the variable on its own:

```
open( my $fh, '<', $file_name)
```

Answer (score 8):

You've put `$file_name` inside single quotes. Single quotes are non-interpolating, so you are trying to read a file called "$file_name", not a file called "whatever is stored in the $file_name scalar".

Remove the quotes.

Comment: or use: open( my $fh, '<', "$file_name")

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to do that?  The quotes in `"$file_name"` are useless.  Just plain `$file_name` is exactly equivalent and cleaner, to boot.